# react redux promise reject making mutiple api call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-redux in my application. It communicates with backend API. When there is any error it should dispaly an alert message.

Follwing is my action:

```
function getByStatus(code) {
    return dispatch => {
        StoreService.getByStatus(code)
            .then(
            users => {
                 ......
            }
            ).catch(error => { 
                dispatch(failure(error));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error));  // problem here
                console.log(error);         
            });
    };

   function failure(error) { return { type:Constants.GETALL_FAILURE, error } } 
}
```

if i add `dispatch(alertActions.error(error))` in the catch the code is **making repeated call to the api**.

[image]

I am calling my action in `componentWillMount`  like below

```
componentWillMount() {    
    const { dispatch } = this.props;    
    dispatch(ReviewActions.getByStatus(1));
}
```

when i remove `dispatch(alertActions.error(error))`, It is not making repeated call.

Can you please hlep me

- How can i dispatch alert action in my code ?
- What went wrong when i
  add alert action dispatch?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong without more code. However, it's generally discouraged to make api calls from `componentWillMount()`. Maybe try `componentDidMount()` instead.

Comment: @TPorter , Same issue with componentDidMount also.  Onething i noted is, I have created a button to make the request instead of page load event. When i click the button. It is making only one API call and alert is woking fine.     <button onClick={this.getdataforReview.bind(this)}> getdata </button>    getPatchForReview() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;

        dispatch(ReviewActions.getByStatus(1));
    }